# Snowflake SQL compilation error: cannot change column from type TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) to TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

Tags: ddl

I have a snowflake database table currently defined like

```
CREATE TABLE lightsaber (
    ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    APPLIED_ON TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I would like to change the column `APPLIED_ON` from `TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9)` to `TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)`. I've read https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html. From there I gather that I should execute

```
alter table lightsaber alter APPLIED_ON set data type TIMESTAMP_NTZ ;
```

However it outputs the error

> SQL compilation error: cannot change column APPLIED_ON from type TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) to TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

I've tried a few other variations with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not going to work, as (per documentation) when setting the TYPE for a column in alter, the specified type (i.e. type) must be NUMBER or a text data type (VARCHAR, STRING, TEXT, etc.) and there are some limitations on how this can be used too - thing is Snowflake does not automatically know how to make data conversion so the options to change data types are not full.

maybe try the more complex path of adding a new column with desired data type, copying the data and removing old column?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are reading this in 2022, **the situation remains the same**, [SnowFlake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html) describes the supported/unsupported actions for modifying column properties.

**Changing column data type to a different type (e.g. STRING to NUMBER) is not supported**. The only option would be to remove the column, add a new one with a new type, or drop the table and recreate it.